# How to write OpenGL ES fragment shaders in XCode?

Tags: swift, opengl-es, sprite-kit, skspritenode, fragment-shader

I'm trying to make my own shader to use as an SKShader for an SKSpriteNode, but I just don't know the proper way to do it. All I want is a way to write the shader code with autocompletion and to see the shader without having to wait ages for some huge program to compile it, but it seems to be more difficult than I thought.

I've already installed GLFW3 and a couple of other odd things since most tutorials suggest something like this for using OpenGL, but it seems to be more for OpenGL as a whole, rather than just one specific kind of shader.

TL;DR: Does anyone know a fast and simple way to write shaders to use as SKShaders in SpriteKit?

Comment: What are you really wanting shaders for? Shaders are not difficult but when people look for "fast" and "easy" it many times indicates they haven't thought things through. Shaders are easy to setup but more difficult to debug/get right depending on what you are doing and scope

Comment: By fast and easy I mean easy as in it has autocompletion so you don't keep stuffing up every 5 seconds, and fast as in you don't have to compile the entire thing for it to work. Doesn't seem this is possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SpriteKit Scene Editor in Xcode. When you associate a shader source file with a node in the inspector, the scene view immediately gives you a live preview of that shader in effect.

Then you can use Xcode's assistant editor pane to see and edit the source of the shader is associated with the currently selected node in the scene — complete with live preview of any animation in the shader (from the `u_time` input).

[image: Xcode shader editing]

That gets you syntax highlighting, but not autocomplete. Xcode's completion engine seems to be limited to its main compiler toolchain — getting it to support shaders in general is certainly a good thing to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.

Editing the shader source should update the live preview, but there seem to be at least some Xcode versions where you have to re-select the custom shader in the inspector for changes to take effect. (That's probably also worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) on...)

---

Shader code in the above example (courtesy [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldXGz7) via [Endless Wave blog](http://endlesswavesoftware.com/blog/spritekit-shaders/)):

```
void main(void) {

    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord;

    uv.y += (cos((uv.y + (u_time * 0.04)) * 45.0) * 0.0019) +
    (cos((uv.y + (u_time * 0.5)) * 10.0) * 0.002);

    uv.x += (sin((uv.y + (u_time * 0.07)) * 15.0) * 0.0029) +
    (sin((uv.y + (u_time * 0.5)) * 15.0) * 0.002);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
}
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks... but thanks so much, I was really getting desperate! Also, thanks to everyone else for taking the time to write examples showing me how SpriteKit worked - even though I already knew I'm sure it'll help someone in the future.

Comment: Okay... just one last question. How could I refresh the preview so I can see any changes I made to the shader? The only way I've found is to change the node's shader to be nothing and then to change it back to my shader, but is there another faster way?

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with your sprite

```
let spaceship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
```

[image]

### The SKShader object

You need to connect it to an `SKShader` object

```
spaceship.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "MyShader.fsh")
```

### The shader code

Next you can create your `MyShader.fsh` file and write inside it the logic for your fragment shader.

In the following example I am setting to `0` the `blue` component of each pixel

```
void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
    color.b = 0.0;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to apply a shader to a sprite, what I'm asking is how I should be writing the shader file (and if it's possible to see it without waiting for the whole thing to compile again). Is there a way to get autocompletion for it?

Comment: @MysteryPancake: Nope, just create an empty file in Xcode, give it the `.fsh` extension and write the OpenGL Shading Language code.

Comment: I think I'll wait to see if someone has a better way. I don't like working in the blind trying to figure out why the shader crashes every time I change something

Answer (score 1):

A working spritekit shader that is very very simple can be found at my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post19_spritekit_bw_shader) on the subject. You should work from an existing example instead of starting from scratch. A number of useful links to shader info are included.

Comment: I'm not really looking for an example though, I've already made a project with a working shader. The question I've been really trying to ask is how to write shaders fast- and by fast I mean with autocompletion (if possible), and with (maybe) live previewing... except from the last two responses it seems there's no way to do this. Oh well.

Comment: No, not really possible. Shaders are some of the most complex code you could possibly write. You need to understand every detail of every floating point operation, nothing is going to make that go faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for auto-complete, I don't believe you can do it in Xcode, but there are other options. For example for Atom:

https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-glsl

There are other stuff out there as well. While autocomplete will help, there are plenty of other ways to have compilation issues. Just like normal coding through Xcode for ObjC/Swift .. you have have correctly auto-completed code. But it still can break. You're far better off exerting energy coming up with an optimized path to get out errors and to test your shader.

If you're experimenting with shaders, you can just setup either a simple app to do your tests or have some isolated mode in your game to do this (which is what I do).

keep in mind, you're not going to be programming shaders all the time. These tend to be few and far between in the course of building a game (assuming you're doing a game, so if not, then this statement may have no validity).